# Problem with encoding when using HtmlAgilityPack to scrape a website

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am scraping a website and it has a single quote in a title.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.AutoDetectEncoding = false;
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
htmlDocument = web.Load(url);
HtmlNode titleNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='content-title']/a")[0];
string title = titleNode.InnerText;
```

The single quote shows up as `&#039;` in the result. How can I get it to show up as a single quote?

I have already tried to manually override the encoding:

```
web.AutoDetectEncoding = false;
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

This didn't work. Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Its probably a problem of interpreting the literal single quote and not the text, try adding $ before the string, if that doesnt work try adding the escape character before the ' which is \

Comment: I saw that my question wasn't clear. 

`string title = titleNode.InnerText;`
The title variable has the `&#039;` instead of a '.

Comment: [HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks HtmlDecode was the solution!